# Django group permissions like linux file system permissions

Tags: django, permissions, usergroups

Basically I would like to have a permission system like Linux file system. I want to classify the permissions whether the user is in the same group as the owner (creator) of the object.

Example scenario:

```
User can change objects created by someone in the same group as them.

Group Admins can change and delete any object created by users in their group.
```

Is it possible to do this with default django permission system? If not, is there a package you could recommend?

I hope I am not missing anything basic in django docs but I couldn't find a way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can add users to groups and write custom methods to check for each action if the user is allowed to do it. You could also add `Boolean` fields to the User model and check for that in the view or another function. example: `if user.userprofile.is_admin: ... `

Comment: That's what I thought to do but I wasn't sure if circumventing django permission system would be secure.